# Problem in Writing data to Excel Sheet using Java

Tags: java, jxl

I have to write some data to an Excel sheet using Java. I searched a video lecture on youtube -https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHodZArY9ns. Their code is perfectly working in the video lecture but when I try to run that code on my laptop, I get the error that the "constructor Label(int, int, String) is undefined". I have added the jxl.jar and done everything I could do. Please help.
The code written below is written in the main method of the class.

```
File f= new File("C:\\Users\\Manu Chaudhary\\Desktop\\ThesisExcel.xls");
WritableWorkbook myexcel= Workbook.createWorkbook(f);
WritableSheet mysheet= myexcel.createSheet("mysheet",0);
Label l= new Label(0,0,"data 1");
mysheet.addCell(l);
myexcel.write();
myexcel.close();
System.out.println("Finish");
```

Comment: Check the version of your JXL JAR.  This javadoc page suggests that your code should be fine, but perhaps the problem is caused by a version change: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/jxl/write/Label.html

Comment: Show us the whole code. From which library is your class Label?

Comment: I suggest you use Apache POI.

Comment: First i used jxl-2.6.jar. I was getting the error. Then i searched jxl.jar, then also the error. The error suggests that the constructor  Label(int,int,String) does not exist.

Comment: Hi Long, i am writing this code in  main method of Java.

Comment: I tried it out of curiosity with the maven dependency net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl version 2.6.12 and your code runs just fine. You should be aware of the fact that this video is 5 years old and a lot of things happened since then. I am with Sedrick and suggest using POI, too. (https://poi.apache.org/) JXL does not seem to be maintained and does not support Office Open XML format.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found some where that new Label(0,0,"data 1")  to be replaced with new jxl.write.Label(0,0,"data 1") and it worked. Thank you everyone.